# Parse SDK iOS - Push notifications only appear when app is in foreground

Tags: ios, parse-platform, apple-push-notifications

I'm using the Parse api to send push notifications between mobile iOS devices. However when the app is in the background the notifications don't arrive.

things I've checked:

-settings of my app to receive notifications are set

-required background modes is set

[image: required background modes is set]

-app capabilities are set

[image]

-registering for notifications is done after facebook authentication

```
- (void) authenticateUserWithFacebook {
NSArray *permissionsArray = @[@"user_relationships",@"user_friends",@"read_friendlists",@"publish_actions"];

[PFFacebookUtils logInWithPermissions:permissionsArray block:^(PFUser *user, NSError *error) {

    if (!user) {
        if (!error) {
            NSLog(@"Uh oh. The user cancelled the Facebook login.");
        } else {
            NSLog(@"Uh oh. An error occurred: %@", error);
            [[PFFacebookUtils session] closeAndClearTokenInformation];
            [[PFFacebookUtils session] close];
            [[FBSession activeSession] closeAndClearTokenInformation];
            [[FBSession activeSession] close];
            [FBSession setActiveSession:nil];
            [PFUser logOut];
            [FBSession renewSystemCredentials:^(ACAccountCredentialRenewResult result, NSError *error) {
                NSLog(@"%@",error);
                [self authenticateUserWithFacebook];
            }];
        }
    } else if (user.isNew) {
        NSLog(@"User with facebook signed up and logged in!");

        [FBRequestConnection startForMeWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
            [[PFUser currentUser] setObject:[result valueForKey:@"id"] forKey:kFbIdKey];
            [[PFUser currentUser] setObject:[result valueForKey:@"name"] forKey:@"name"];
            [[PFUser currentUser] saveInBackground];
        }];
        [self loadUsersFacebookFriends];
        if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] respondsToSelector:@selector(registerUserNotificationSettings:)]){
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:(UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge) categories:nil]];
        } else {
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
             (UIUserNotificationTypeBadge | UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert)];
        }

    } else {
        NSLog(@"User with facebook logged in!");

        [FBRequestConnection startForMeWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
            [[PFUser currentUser] setObject:[result valueForKey:@"id"] forKey:kFbIdKey];
            [[PFUser currentUser] setObject:[result valueForKey:@"name"] forKey:@"name"];
            [[PFUser currentUser] saveInBackground];
        }];

        if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] respondsToSelector:@selector(registerUserNotificationSettings:)]){
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:(UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge) categories:nil]];
        } else{
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
             (UIUserNotificationTypeBadge | UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert)];

        }
    }
}];
}
```

-registered delegate methods get fired when starting the app

```
 - (void) application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken {
   PFInstallation *currentInstallation = [PFInstallation currentInstallation];
   [currentInstallation setDeviceTokenFromData:deviceToken];
   [currentInstallation setObject:[[PFUser currentUser] objectForKey:@"fbId"] forKey:kOwnerKey];
   [currentInstallation saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
if (error)
  NSLog(@"error %@",error);
}];        
}

- (void) application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterUserNotificationSettings:(UIUserNotificationSettings *)notificationSettings {
        [application registerForRemoteNotifications];
}
```

-notification delegate method is called only when in foreground

```
- (void) application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler {
```

-I also tried with a new provisioning profile. same result.

-I've also never seen the pop up notification that the app wants to send notifications.

Comment: this ios8 for is only?

Comment: well I omitted the iOS7 part just to have a bit less code here.

Comment: plz at least add where you actually call registerUserSettings

Comment: if you say you don't see the box. is the app then even listed in the settings app

Comment: yes it's listed in the settings app. I've updated my answer to show where I call it.

Comment: try asking for alert, banner & sound permissions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found where the problem was.
I was sending the push notifications the wrong way.
this only works when the app is in the foreground.

```
[PFPush sendPushDataToQueryInBackground:pushQuery withData:gameData];
```

this is the code I need to use.

```
[PFPush sendPushMessageToQueryInBackground:pushQuery withMessage:@"test"];
```

Comment: When the app is in background,the data from push JSON payload is used to show alerts,badge etc.If payload don't have alert key,it won't display push.The same thing happend for you also